# Connection loss

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, router, internet

I have an office network setup. it's a work-group and the problem is that, in one computer the user cannot connect to websites. The network connection shows that it has internet access, but the browser displays an error message! when the user restart the computer, the problem goes away.

I used the ping command while the problem was there, and the ping command completed successfully to google.com.

what can be the fault in this specific pc. my 10 PCs are connected to a router with internet access via a 24 port standard switch.

Comment: Are websites the only problem on that computer? Or do other internet services (e.g. ssh, pop3, imap, ...) also fail? If it is just websites which fail then check your proxy settings.  Also, please include the precise error message from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess this is a problem with the DNS on the machine. Check to see if it is set up as either static or dynamic IP and DNS.

Start -> Control Panel -> Network and sharing center.

On the left, click on Change adapter settings.

Right click the connection in use and select properties.

Scroll to Internet Protocol Version 4 and then select properties.

This screen may help as you can change the DNS. From within this screen you can also click Advanced to ensure DHCP is enabled and to see what DNS is in use (from the DNS tab).

Also, try it with your internet security suite turned off and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I checked the DNS settings and it states to obtain the DNS automatically. and the DHCP is turned on too.